# Hibernate - Extending Entities without a base table annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, superclass

I have the following 2 `Hiberante` entities:

```
Person

Animal
```

They have the shared fields / columns e.g: `name, age` etc, however each primary key id field is named differently, e.g. there is `person_id` and `animal_id`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Integer person_id;

    // all below fields are generic in all the entities
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "age")
    private String age;

}
```

Is there a way that I can create a base entity super class that holds these generic `name, age` etc fields, then have Person, Animal and any new entities extend this super entity?

Note that the super class does not have a table of its own so I am not sure what I would have for the `@Table` value?

I also have the issue of the primary keys not all being named e.g. `id` so would have to specify them specifically in each entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add a table in your database for this "super entity" (let's call the class `Being`), you can still make `Person` and `Animal` inherit from it (`Person` should inherit from `Animal` BTW), and do the mapping of the common fields on properties:

```
public abstract class Being {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // ...

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person extends Being {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    // all below fields are generic in all the entities
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        super.setName(name);
    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: Thanks does this in some way take away from the point of the abstract class though? I still have to create getters and setters for the generic fields in each of the child objects? Also, I cant see why anyone would have a table in their DB for being, as this would just be duplicated in either person or animal?

Comment: @java12399900 yes. The `Being` class does not have to be `abstract`, but instances would not be persisted. It can make sense to have a table for a high level classe, even if it's abstract, to have a better mapping between the Java classes and the SQL tables, and less redundant fields/columns (and to avoid adding redundant getters/setters).